# question about Lagrange theorem

Tags: calculus

Does the Mean Value Theorem apply for the function $y= \left| \ln{x} \right|$ in the segment $(1/e, e)$, It seems to me that by the graph the function is continous in this segment and differentiable, can someone give me some help analytically

Comment: Which one of Lagrange's many theorems are you referring to?

Comment: sorry I was referring to the MVT, I edited

Comment: Can you help me with a hint?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the derivative of the logarithm?

Comment: yes its 1/x but it's on absolute value

Comment: The interval you are asking about contains only positive numbers, so you don't need the absolute value.

Comment: no the ln(1/e) is -1

Comment: The domain of $\log$ is $ \{ x: x>0 \} $. Its range is the whole real line, but the derivative is defined on the domain of the function. (or possibly only a subset of the domain if the function is not differentiable everywhere).

(And you can see that the range of the function is not actually relevant, since $1+\log{x}$ has the same derivative, for example.)

Comment: Yes but can you give an answer for the MVT in this case if we have the function absolute value of lnx in the segment (1/e;e)

Comment: Oh, you mean $|\log{x}|$?

Comment: yes but i didn't know how to write it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The function $|\log{x}|$ is not differentiable at $1$, basically because near $1$, $\log{x}$ looks like $x-1$, so locally you have $|\log{x}| \approx |x-1|$, and the absolute value function is not differentiable at $0$.

To see it more rigorously, compute the derivative quotient at $1$.